# measures on a measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{F})$ is measurable space where $\mathcal{F}$ is the algebra of all subsets of $X$. Let $\mu , \nu$ be two measures on $X$. Let

$$ A = \{ x : \mu( \{x \} ) = 0 \} $$

$$ B = \{ x : \nu( \{ x \} ) = 0 \} $$

MY question is:

$A \subseteq B$ is equivalent to saying that $\nu << \mu$ ( $\nu$ absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$) ???

thanks

Comment: Take $\mu$ to be the Diract delta measure, $\delta_0$, say, and $\nu$ to be the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\nu\ll \mu$, then $\mu\{x\}=0$ implies $\nu\{x\}=0$, hence $A\subseteq B$.

But $A$ and $B$ only describe the behavior of the measures over singletons. It's not enough to conclude absolute continuity of them. Take for example the interval $[0,2]$ with Lebesgue measure, and $\mu(S)=\lambda(S\cap (0,1))$, $\nu(S)=\lambda(S\cap (1,2))$. Then the corresponding $A$ and $B$ are $[0,2]$, but $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not absolutely continuous.